# Why does the '!head' command list file content?

Tags: linux, unix

```
!head -n5 {train_dataset_fp}
```

Where train_dataset_fp is a str object in Python:

```
In [147]: train_dataset_fp                                                                                                                                        
Out[147]: '/home/martin/.keras/datasets/iris_training.csv'
```

How can the above 'head' command display the content of the file:

```
120,4,setosa,versicolor,virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,2
5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,1
4.9,2.5,4.5,1.7,2
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,0
```

What's the '!head'? I know what 'head' command means.

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system and its utilities should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

head is a linux command  that show the n first lines of any file. The ! means  execute a OS Shell,  then !head run a Shell and execute head command. The parameter  -n5 is for first 5 lines.

Comment: which exact shell that can read content from a file through a string {}?

Comment: To show current Shell execute:  !echo $0